Can a python script communicate with an Arduino sketch via the same port on your pc?
I was trying to establish communication where by an arduino sketch should send data to a python script via the same port of my computer. However, that communication failed since the port becomes busy after being used by an arduino sketch. In fact, I'm told that the communication via that port is not possible for I'm  for it isn't available.
I tried to change my codes and see if the problem is within my code, but it was in vain.
So I'm wondering if there is other way my port can be used by the sript and the arduino sketch at the same time.

it's not the sketch that ties up the serial port on a PC ... it is the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE that ties it up

Thanks, but is there a way to solve that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

is there a way to solve that? ... release the COM port so that python can use it
